# Preprocessing image for Tesseract OCR with OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to develop an App that uses Tesseract to recognize text from documents taken by a phone's cam. I'm using OpenCV to preprocess the image for better recognition, applying a Gaussian blur and a Threshold method for binarization, but the result is pretty bad.

[Here](https://s6.postimg.cc/sft9tot9d/0_img02.png) is the the image I'm using for tests:
[image]

And [here](https://s6.postimg.cc/mswww7qqp/2_img02_sharpened_threshold1.png) the preprocessed image:
[image]

What others filter can I use to make the image more readable for Tesseract?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I described some tips for preparing images for Tesseract here:
[Using tesseract to recognize license plates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268648/using-tesseract-to-recognize-license-plates/19418347#19418347)

In your example, there are several things going on...

You need to get the text to be black and the rest of the image white (*not* the reverse).  That's what character recognition is tuned on.  Grayscale *is* ok, as long as the background is mostly full white and the text mostly full black; the edges of the text may be gray (antialiased) and that *may* help recognition (but not necessarily - you'll have to experiment)

One of the issues you're seeing is that in some parts of the image, the text is really "thin" (and gaps in the letters show up after thresholding), while in other parts it is really "thick" (and letters start merging).  Tesseract won't like that :)  It happens because the input image is not evenly lit, so a single threshold doesn't work everywhere.  The solution is to do "locally adaptive thresholding" where a different threshold is calculated for each neighbordhood of the image.  There are many ways of doing that, but check out for example:

- [Adaptive gaussian thresholding in OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html) with `cv2.adaptiveThreshold(...,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,...)`
- [Local Otsu's method](http://sharky93.github.io/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_local_otsu.html)
- [Local adaptive histogram equalization](http://sharky93.github.io/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_local_equalize.html)

Another problem you have is that the lines aren't straight.  In my experience Tesseract can handle a *very limited* degree of non-straight lines (a few percent of perspective distortion, tilt or skew), but it doesn't really work with *wavy* lines.  If you can, make sure that the source images have straight lines :)  Unfortunately, there is no simple off-the-shelf answer for this; you'd have to look into the research literature and implement one of the state of the art algorithms yourself (and open-source it if possible - there is a real need for an open source solution to this).  A Google Scholar search for "[curved line OCR extraction](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=curved%20line%20OCR%20extraction&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&as_vis=1)" will get you started, for example:

- [Text line Segmentation of Curved Document Images](http://www.academia.edu/7675762/S_Text_line_Segmentation_of_Curved_Document_Images)

Lastly: I think you would do much better to work with the python ecosystem (ndimage, skimage) than with OpenCV in C++.  OpenCV python wrappers are ok for simple stuff, but for what you're trying to do they won't do the job, you will need to grab many pieces that aren't in OpenCV (of course you can mix and match).  Implementing something like curved line detection in C++ will take an order of magnitude longer than in python (* this is true even if you don't know python).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried with straight lines pictures and AdaptiveThreshold and got not perfect but pretty decent results. I'll be looking into the curved lines problem and will open-source the solution when I get to it. Finally I will take your suggestion and work with python at least for this task.

Comment: Unfortunately your links are not working anymore. I would be very interested as well..

Comment: Updated Links: [Adaptive gaussian thresholding in OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html), [Local Otsu's method](http://sharky93.github.io/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_local_otsu.html), [Local adaptive histogram equalization](http://sharky93.github.io/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_local_equalize.html)  A simple google inurl search can fix a lot of broken links

Comment: Can you update the external links in your answer? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what preprocessing steps does tesseract engine perform on an image? Like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50451577/2286337), tesseract is able to detect text from color images so it must be performing some steps before recognition.

Answer (score 28):

> 1. Scanning at 300 dpi (dots per inch) is not officially a standard for OCR (optical character recognition), but it is considered the gold standard.
> 2. Converting image to Greyscale improves accuracy in reading text in general.

I have written a module that reads text in Image which in turn process the image for optimum result from OCR, [Image Text Reader](http://github.com/yardstick17/image_text_reader) .

```py
import tempfile

import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

IMAGE_SIZE = 1800
BINARY_THREHOLD = 180

def process_image_for_ocr(file_path):
    # TODO : Implement using opencv
    temp_filename = set_image_dpi(file_path)
    im_new = remove_noise_and_smooth(temp_filename)
    return im_new

def set_image_dpi(file_path):
    im = Image.open(file_path)
    length_x, width_y = im.size
    factor = max(1, int(IMAGE_SIZE / length_x))
    size = factor * length_x, factor * width_y
    # size = (1800, 1800)
    im_resized = im.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    temp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix='.jpg')
    temp_filename = temp_file.name
    im_resized.save(temp_filename, dpi=(300, 300))
    return temp_filename

def image_smoothening(img):
    ret1, th1 = cv2.threshold(img, BINARY_THREHOLD, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    ret2, th2 = cv2.threshold(th1, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(th2, (1, 1), 0)
    ret3, th3 = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    return th3

def remove_noise_and_smooth(file_name):
    img = cv2.imread(file_name, 0)
    filtered = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img.astype(np.uint8), 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 41,
                                     3)
    kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
    opening = cv2.morphologyEx(filtered, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
    closing = cv2.morphologyEx(opening, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
    img = image_smoothening(img)
    or_image = cv2.bitwise_or(img, closing)
    return or_image
```

Comment: Somehow even after this much refining, tesseract is still not able to detect my text on the image..

Any idea what further can be done here...?

Comment: May I ask you to have a look at a Tesseract and OpenCV related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66946835/improving-accuracy-in-python-tesseract-ocr ?

Comment: @yardstick17, It is working well with most images, but for some images the results are quite bad. For images with white text, for example, images with white text on a dark background, the results are not good.

Answer (score 9):

Note: this should be a comment to Alex I answer, but it's too long so i put it as answer.

from "An Overview of the Tesseract OCR engine, by Ray Smith, Google Inc." at https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/docs/blob/master/tesseracticdar2007.pdf

"Processing follows a traditional step-by-step
pipeline, but some of the stages were unusual in their
day, and possibly remain so even now. The first step is
a connected component analysis in which outlines of
the components are stored. This was a computationally
expensive design decision at the time, but had a
significant advantage: by inspection of the nesting of
outlines, and the number of child and grandchild
outlines, it is simple to detect inverse text and
recognize it as easily as black-on-white text. Tesseract
was probably the first OCR engine able to handle
white-on-black text so trivially."

So it seems it's not needed to have black text on white background, and should work the opposite too.

Comment: this is old doc - not valid for tesseract 4.x

Comment: @user898678, so can you show me an example that is working well with tesseract 4.x?

Comment: just provide black letter on white background as input (e.g. already binarized image)

Answer (score 2):

You can play around with the configuration of the OCR by changing the --psm and --oem values, in your case specifically I will suggest using

--psm 3
--oem 2

you can also look at the following link for further details
[here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/doc/tesseract.1.asc#config-files-and-augmenting-with-user-data)

Answer (score 1):

For wavy text like yours there is this fantastic Python code on GitHub, which transforms the text to straight lines: https://github.com/tachylatus/page_dewarp.git (this is the most updated version of MZucker's original post and the mechanics are explained here:https://mzucker.github.io/2016/08/15/page-dewarping.html)

Answer (score -1):

I guess you have used the generic approach for Binarization, that is the reason whole image is not binarized uniformly. You can use Adaptive Thresholding technique for binarization. You can also do some skew correction, perspective correction, noise removal for better results.

Refer to this medium [article](https://medium.com/@susmithreddyvedere/pre-processing-in-ocr-fc231c6035a7), to know about the above-mentioned techniques along with code samples.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer before answering. In this case, don't post links that may one day disappear. Instead try to put all necessary info into your answer.