# Preprocessing tilted text for Tesseract OCR using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to identify the words on the back of a medicine pack, This is an example of my picture.
[image: this but better quality] :

Since the text is tilted, where should I start in trying to auto-rotate it such the OCR works?

I've looked at [this document](http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/09/opencv-detect-skew-angle/)  and [this other question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28935983/preprocessing-image-for-tesseract-ocr-with-opencv/28936254#28936254) but in these cases the text is more than one or two words so the textlines are longer.

Comment: Please check your image format.and edit it.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean? Something wrong with the image link?

Comment: No,But just edit it with ``markdown`` format,it can make people who want to answer your question more convenient.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't embed images as a new poster but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: You’re going to need **Much** better quality images

Comment: Did you actually try the methods in the pages you linked to? Hough line detection can work even with shorter lines (you control how long lines it will detect) though no doubt you would have to adapt to your specific images.